# Order of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $n$ is the least positive integer such that:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\pi}{4} & \sin \frac{\pi}{4}\\
            -\sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4}\end{pmatrix}^n$$
is the identity matrix of order $2$, then what is $n$?

Comment: Whats your idea about how to proceed/start

Answer (score 7):

Hint: the matrix
$R(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ represents a clockwise rotation by an angle $\theta$. So $R(\theta)^n=R(n\theta)$.